# Powerline patched font not working on Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal, font, vi, zsh

I am on Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C2513).
I am using Inconsolata patched font from [here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts). But I also tried to patch the font myself.
The result is the following:

[image: Inconsolata]

I am able to see the glyphs but `zsh` (see the glyph next to the branch name `develop` for a git repository) and also `vim` fail to display them on Terminal.app

Am I missing any configuration step?

### Update

Using Input Mono v1.100 I have the same problem:

[image: Input Mono]

Comment: Is it possible some apps will not display private use area codepoints?

Comment: Hi, how can I test it?

Comment: Try the font in a different app

Comment: I tried also ITerm2 but same results. In case I will post also screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For zsh:

I found that the theme I was using was defining the branch glyph in a wrong way. In particular, I corrected defining on my theme file the variable `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX=" %{$FG[075]%}<glyph> "` where `<glyph>` is the symbol you want to use to represent git branch.

For vim:

I found the solution in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106718/102126).

> because 0x2B60 and the others do not exist anymore you just have to update autoload/Pl/Parser.vim to look something like this:

```
    \ 'fancy': {
        \   'dividers': [ [0xe0b0], [0xe0b1], [0xe0b2], [0xe0b3] ]
        \ , 'symbols' : {
                \   'BRANCH': [0xe0a0]
                \ , 'RO'    : [0xe0a4]
                \ , 'FT'    : [0xe0a2, 0xe0a3]
                \ , 'LINE'  : [0xe0a1]
        \ },
    \ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest you to install [Input Mono](http://input.fontbureau.com) font, comes with full support to powerline.

In order the following to work, Input Mono font must be version 1.1. You can check the font version by going to `Font Book → View → Show Font Info`, and look at the version number.

With Terminal.app works out of the box. Just select the font and you are ready.

With iTerm2, you have to modify a couple of things:

- Go to Preferences → Profiles → Text and uncheck `Use a different font for non-ASCII text.
- Just above, click on `Change Font` and select Input Mono. Additionally you have to change `Character Spacing → Vertical` to 110%. Seems that Terminal and iTerm2 render character spacing in a different way.

Comment: Really strange, in my case just works out of the box.

Comment: +1 for iTerm2 explanation - worked on OSX Sierra like a charm